# Remain on my site or transfer to paypal?

Tags: paypal, user-experience

Generally, which would customers prefer? To remain on my site or be transferred to paypal to complete a purchase?

Do customers prefer the security of a paypal branded page? or would users prefer to remain on my site and process payments through the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty it's probably worth sending them off to paypal. Most 'buyers' online wont have a preference as they don't quite understand it. Yet, some will be re-assured that they're interacting with a familiar brand.

I've had this with some sites that I've written. Some people wont even register on the site for fear of people stealing their information. The funny thing is, these people will then phone the store and happily give all important information over the phone. It's madness! :)

I guess it all comes down to the individual, but redirecting to Paypal and having them complete it there is probably the easiest option. HTH!

Comment: Reason for asking is that i was concerned about whether the extra steps of logging into paypal to complete a transaction would put people off, compared to a seamless experience with it all handled via the api.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. Unfortunately it's one of those things that people of the web are fickle about. Some like not being prompted, others think you're about to take their details and drive to their house to steal their cat! In all honesty, I'd go with what you feel happy with. As I've said previously, I've sent people off to complete via the PayPal site, because they're more familiar with that brand and thus trust it a bit more. It's catch 22 really :) Sorry I couldn't be any more help!